# Make input element invisible

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mobile

Hi I try to get a variable of a specific list item. I want to realize that with a invisible input element an set there the value, in this case of the time, and try to get the value of the variable on a simple php if condition. That the invisibilty, that should mean that the user wont see the input element, I tried to do it with jquery 1.8.2 but it wont work. What should I change? Suggested improvements on how to get a value of a list item in php are welcome.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#timex").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "0") {
            $("#timex").hide();
        }

    });
});
```

my html code within a foreach loop:

```
<a href="#popupcomment" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">comment</a> 
<div data-role="popup" id="popupcomment" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
    <form data-ajax="false" name="login-form" class="login-form" action="./range.php" method="post" style="padding:20px 40px;">
        <div class="content">
            <input name="timex" id="timex" value="<?php echo $row['time']; ?>" type="text" />
            <textarea rows="5" name="text" id="text" class="foo"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <input type="submit" name="save" value="comment" class="button" data-theme="a" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is input type="hidden"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the snippet, and change the value to 0 (and hit enter).

**Note:** Changing the `type` attribute only works with a newer version of jQuery.
`.hide()` works with jQuery 1.8.2

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#timex").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "0") {
            $(this).attr('type', 'hidden');
        }
    });
  
    $("#timey").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "0") {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<input name="timex" id="timex" value="5" type="text" />
<input name="timey" id="timey" value="8" type="text" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```